# How to scroll a parent control with the mouse wheel while the mouse is hovering over a child control?

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, mouseevent, parent-child

This is a general question with a specific example:

I have a `TableLayoutPanel` and the property `AutoScroll` is `true`. The `TableLayoutPanel` contains `ListView`s.

When the mouse is hovering over the parent control (in this case it's the `TableLayoutPanel`) and I am scrolling with the mouse wheel, the control moves. So far so good. But when the mouse is hovering over a child control (in this case it's a `ListView` and the property `Scrollable` is `false`) nothing happens.

Is there a simple solution to this problem?

Comment: Hmm, no, nothing simple.  This is controlled by the native Windows component, its LVS_NOSCROLL style flag selects behavior.  You'd have to derive your own class from ListView so you can override OnMouseWheel().  And pinvoke SendMessage() to notify the parent.  And beware how differently this works on Win10, on prior versions of Windows the event is raised on the control with the focus.  Try a hook: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ec1fbfa2-137e-49f6-b444-b634e4f44f21/send-a-scroll-down-message-to-listbox-using-mousewheel-but-listbox-doesnt-have-focus?forum=winforms

Comment: How could I solve this problem with the `MouseEventArgs`? For example with `DoMouseWheel`?